# Can Sublime Text Autocomplete CSS Classes?

Tags: html, css, class, autocomplete

Suppose I have this in my index.html:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

And the HTML page is linked to layout.css, is there any way that Sublime Text 2 can make an autocomplete suggestion for .foo when I'm typing something like `.f` or `.fo` (...)?

I'm asking this because a lot of times I'm mistyping a class name and it's takes time to find that out. This feature, if exists, will help me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had that problem once.By default sublime only completes words on the opened file.I found that [sublimeallautocomplete](https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete/) has a solution for that.But you have to open both css and html on sublime so that it looks words on files opened in sublime.you better look on sublimetext forums also.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Just installing All Autocomplete didn't solve the problem for me inside .css files (it worked only in .html files).
For anyone having similar issue, this is the solution: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/283